# How to check if the file obtained from a call to facebook's api is really an image?

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I made a call to the facebook's graph API and retreieved an image. Now i want to check if the image coming from the call is really an image file or not.
I wrote the code for a simple image checking function. How do I pass a url to `$path` variable. I would also be reusing this code to check for images from Twitter too.

```
function is_image($path)
  {
$a = getimagesize($path);
$image_type = $a[2];

if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: `if ( is_image('/path/to/myimage.png') ) { do stuff }`

Comment: i send my url like this. https://graph.facebook.com/<?$user_id?>/picture?size=original
How do I pass it to the function is_image.

Comment: @adeneo, i hope you understood my comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For facebook api case, you can simply make **HTTP HEAD Request** http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?size=original, then it should be a image if the http_code is **HTTP/1.1 302 Found**

Comment: Can i use the same with twitter?

Comment: Should be same, http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=obama&size=bigger, 302 redirect should point to the profile image.

Comment: @user202901 In addition, facebook graph API allow you to get image link in json format without redirect. Kindly check it out on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Answer (score 0):

Run [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on it - if it returns values then it's an image.